# How does FreeNotification work?

Tags: delphi, user-interface, vcl

Currently, I am trying to understand Delphi's VCL, specifically, the notification mechanism (which is a great mechanism in my point of view). 
When I was studying on this subject, I remembered of the `TLabeledEdit`, of course I have been using it for long time, but I never had chance to stop and study it's code.

As I understand so far:

When a TComponent is destroyed:

1. It will notify all its children's components, to include `csDestroying` in its state.
2. `FreeNotifiers` part. I can't understand.
3. Will iterate the `components` list and:

   1. Remove each item from the `components` list
   2. Actually destroy each component instance.

When a child component is being destroyed, it restarts the same process for all of its children components. So, as far as I can tell, this is a chain effect.

What I can't understand is the `FreeNotification`, what could I possibly do with it?

Let's think about the `TLabeledEdit` in first place. The relevant part of the notification, in `TLabeledEdit`'s code is an override on the `Notification` function, with the following code:

```
  if (AComponent = FEditLabel) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    FEditLabel := nil;
```

What could have happened if `FreeNotification` was not used?

In General, what benefits would I have because of this mechanism and what am I not seeing that might eventually make its existence necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the `FreeNotification` mechanism does is *notifies registered components that this component is being freed.*  They then use their `Notification` method to ensure that they don't hold any references to it (which is what your example is doing) so that they don't end up with dangling references to an invalid object.

Comment: Sure. But within the `SetupInternalLabel` function, the `FEditLabel` is created as child of `TCustomLabeledEdit` (`FEditLabel := TBoundLabel.Create(Self);`). So how that could cause dangling reference? I mean, how could I use the label, after destroying the LabeledEdit?

Comment: If one try to access the label like `LabeledEdit1.EditLabel`, it will raise an AV because LabeledEdit1 it is already destroyed.

Comment: You can safely free a nil reference, but you get an exception freeing a reference to an already destroyed instance. Another point is, you can check if assigned

Comment: @PageNotFound: If a non-nil reference exists, you can call things on it.  If what's there is a destroyed object, you might get an access violation, or you might have something that seems to work, but actually ends up corrupting data.  Undefined behavior is a really ugly thing.  Better to nil the reference, and then if someone tries to use it, they're **guaranteed** to get an access violation, and one that's very easy to fix in a debugger.

Comment: Yes. So that is it? Is this the whole purpose of FreeNotification? I was expecting something more magical.

Comment: @MasonWheeler You should also mention the ownership part. The owner is responsible for the owned instances. And so it is necessary to inform the owner that it is no longer responsible for that

Comment: @SirRufo When the owner relinquishes the ownership?

Comment: @PageNotFound When the owned component notifies the owner. This is initiated by calling `FreeNotification` and can be reworded: Notify me, if the instance I'm responsible for gets destroyed not initiated by me, so I can kick this instance from my ResponsibleFor list. Have a look at the source of `TComponent` (start with `constructor Create( Owner : TComponent );`)

Comment: @PageNotFound So `FreeNotification` belongs to that ownership handling of `TComponent`, but it is not limited to.

Answer (score 0):

The point of FreeNotification is to allow you to clean up references to form children in cases where these components close and free themselves. In this example I use a Modal form, the FreeNotification sets the reference to NULL which allows me to detect if the form is still open or already exists if the user creates another one

```
void __fastcall TForm1::OpenForm(TObject *Sender)
{
    frmGetPrint = new TfrmGetPrint(Application);
    frmGetPrint->FreeNotification( this);
    frmGetPrint->Show();
}
```

frmGetPrint must free itself when closed:

```
void __fastcall TfrmSetPrint::FormClose(TObject *Sender, TCloseAction &Action)
{
    Action = caFree;
}
```

You need to create a function in the parent form referred to by *this* in the call to FreeNotification( this), in this case Form1

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Notification(Classes::TComponent* AComponent, 
Classes::TOperation Operation)
{
    if( AComponent == frmGetPrint && Operation == opRemove)
        frmGetPrint = NULL;
}
```